# Issues with JavaScript in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

This is my first day using GEE and I am running accross issues with my script. I am trying to create an image collection on Sentinel-2 images within the province of Nova Scotia during June 1 - August 31st, 2020. I am then trying to reduce to one image and calculate the median for bands B2, B3, B4 and B8.  I am getting error messages on line 10 and 12 where it says "missing ";"before statement. Any idea how to fix this script?

[image]

Comment: Please share the code as formatted text rather a screenshot.

Comment: how do I add code as formatted text? I am very new to this.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably with "Var". Javascript is a case sensitive language. The proper way of writing will be small letter "v" same as you declared the first variable `sentColl`.

Comment: This solved that issue but now i have an error saying median is not defined :S